# Eloquent JS example doesn't run anywhere but the EJ sandbox

Tags: javascript, methods, console.log

I just opened up Eloquent JS to sharpen up my JavaScript skills. In the very beginning of the book Haverbeke shows a program written in binary meant to add up the numbers between 1 and 10 and spit out the total.

He then simplifies the program from binary to 1 line of JavaScript. Here is the final code snippet:

```
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// ---> 55
```

I have searched up and down MDN and I do not see any `sum()` or `range()` methods. He talks about the Eloquent's sandbox environment and that some code may not run in other interpreters, but this just boggles me.

I understand what the program is meant to do, but I don't know where he got `sum()` and `range()` from. Am I missing something/overthinking? Is this purely for explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the webpage of [Eloquent js](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/) you can see that he added a seperate JavascriptFile called Intro.js

That's where you'll find the missing functions:

```
function range(start, end, step) {
  if (step == null) step = 1;
  var array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
      array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    total += array[i];
  return total;
}
```

So you could download that js and include it into your enviroment.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to look at the code files! I appreciate it Jeff I thought I was going a little crazy haha

Comment: The author does not do a good job of explaining where one can run JavaScript outside of the sandbox. It would be nice is the author explained a little about combining JavaScript with HTML using <script></script> or an external script file. It's a mostly good book, but it is as if the author totally blanked that aspect of JavaScript as if it did not exist.